# Will the pressure inside a pressing mold will be constant if I'm working with a fluid inside?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, glass

I'm pressing glass and I want to know if the pressure that the walls of my mold feel is the same through all the internal surfaces. I'm willing to assume that glass will behave purely as a fluid (very viscous) in the temperature range I'm working it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in an enclosed container, with fluid at rest, the pressure is equal on all the walls and at any point inside the container.

The fluid at rest indicates the Kinetic energy of the fluid,

$ \ E =\frac{1}{2}\dot{m}v^2 $

is insignificant, there is no rapid flow of matter.

It is Pascal’s law.

This law is used in hydraulic presses as well.